# docker can't connect to docker daemon but socket is created

Tags: docker, ubuntu

My problem is that I can use `docker` with for example Portainer but when I run `docker` on the machine on sudo `docker` can't connect to the daemon and tells me about it:

All commands are done with root.

```
docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

docker service:

```
systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
             └─options.conf
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-10-22 19:02:54 UTC; 4 days ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 182765 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 175
     Memory: 93.1M
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             ├─182765 /usr/bin/dockerd -H unix:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
             ├─182942 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 49153 -container-ip 172.17.0.2 -container-port 27017
             ├─182949 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip :: -host-port 49153 -container-ip 172.17.0.2 -container-port 27017
             ├─182962 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 8081 -container-ip 172.18.0.2 -container-port 8080
             ├─182970 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip :: -host-port 8081 -container-ip 172.18.0.2 -container-port 8080
             ├─182984 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 6881 -container-ip 172.18.0.2 -container-port 6881
             ├─182990 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip :: -host-port 6881 -container-ip 172.18.0.2 -container-port 6881
             ├─183004 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto udp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 6881 -container-ip 172.18.0.2 -container-port 6881
             ├─183010 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto udp -host-ip :: -host-port 6881 -container-ip 172.18.0.2 -container-port 6881
             ├─183034 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 49154 -container-ip 172.17.0.3 -container-port 3306
             ├─183041 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip :: -host-port 49154 -container-ip 172.17.0.3 -container-port 3306
             ├─183148 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 49155 -container-ip 172.17.0.4 -container-port 6379
             ├─183154 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip :: -host-port 49155 -container-ip 172.17.0.4 -container-port 6379
             ├─183332 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 9443 -container-ip 172.17.0.5 -container-port 9443
             ├─183339 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip :: -host-port 9443 -container-ip 172.17.0.5 -container-port 9443
             ├─183353 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 9000 -container-ip 172.17.0.5 -container-port 9000
             ├─183360 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip :: -host-port 9000 -container-ip 172.17.0.5 -container-port 9000
             ├─183372 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 8000 -container-ip 172.17.0.5 -container-port 8000
             ├─183378 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip :: -host-port 8000 -container-ip 172.17.0.5 -container-port 8000
             ├─186468 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 8080 -container-ip 172.17.0.6 -container-port 80
             └─186474 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip :: -host-port 8080 -container-ip 172.17.0.6 -container-port 80

Oct 27 09:31:30 falcon dockerd[182765]: time="2021-10-27T09:31:30.218332206Z" level=debug msg="Calling GET /containers/69047b41bedea4794803730ff0fa13a65e546519f9>
Oct 27 09:31:30 falcon dockerd[182765]: time="2021-10-27T09:31:30.219026938Z" level=debug msg="Calling GET /images/json?all=0"
Oct 27 09:32:58 falcon dockerd[182765]: time="2021-10-27T09:32:58.654321683Z" level=debug msg="Calling HEAD /_ping"
Oct 27 09:32:58 falcon dockerd[182765]: time="2021-10-27T09:32:58.656492046Z" level=debug msg="Calling GET /v1.37/info"
Oct 27 09:32:58 falcon dockerd[182765]: time="2021-10-27T09:32:58.673377621Z" level=debug msg="Calling GET /v1.37/containers/json?all=1&limit=0"
Oct 27 09:32:58 falcon dockerd[182765]: time="2021-10-27T09:32:58.680766521Z" level=debug msg="Calling GET /v1.37/images/json"
Oct 27 09:32:58 falcon dockerd[182765]: time="2021-10-27T09:32:58.701618241Z" level=debug msg="Calling GET /v1.37/volumes"
```

I can use portainer as usual

docker version:

```
docker -v
Docker version 20.10.7, build 20.10.7-0ubuntu1~20.04.2
```

More information:

```
ls -l /var/run
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Jul 31  2020 /var/run -> /run
```

docker.sock is created:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   40 Oct 25 20:31 docker.sock
```

```
rcat /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service
[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=https://docs.docker.com
After=network-online.target firewalld.service containerd.service
Wants=network-online.target
Requires=docker.socket
Wants=containerd.service

[Service]
Type=notify
# the default is not to use systemd for cgroups because the delegate issues still
# exists and systemd currently does not support the cgroup feature set required
# for containers run by docker
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
TimeoutSec=0
RestartSec=2
Restart=always

# Note that StartLimit* options were moved from "Service" to "Unit" in systemd 229.
# Both the old, and new location are accepted by systemd 229 and up, so using the old location
# to make them work for either version of systemd.
StartLimitBurst=3

# Note that StartLimitInterval was renamed to StartLimitIntervalSec in systemd 230.
# Both the old, and new name are accepted by systemd 230 and up, so using the old name to make
# this option work for either version of systemd.
StartLimitInterval=60s

# Having non-zero Limit*s causes performance problems due to accounting overhead
# in the kernel. We recommend using cgroups to do container-local accounting.
LimitNOFILE=infinity
LimitNPROC=infinity
LimitCORE=infinity

# Comment TasksMax if your systemd version does not support it.
# Only systemd 226 and above support this option.
TasksMax=infinity

# set delegate yes so that systemd does not reset the cgroups of docker containers
Delegate=yes

# kill only the docker process, not all processes in the cgroup
KillMode=process
OOMScoreAdjust=-500

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Any one got a clue why `docker` is unable to connect to the daemon?

Comment: Are you root? Or have you tried sudo?

Comment: I am root. Tried both.

Comment: All commands are done as root. Error (sudo docker ps or docker ps as root) is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a container configured to bind mount `/var/lib/docker.sock` and the daemon restarted that container before creating the socket. There's been some [tweeks to packaging](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30348#issuecomment-934176416) in recent releases to reduce this chance. Otherwise you may want to mount the entire directory instead of a single file.

To fix, try stopping docker, deleting the empty directory, and restarting docker to see if the socket gets created first (it's a race condition).

Comment: So what I did was, disable autorun on the bind mount `/var/lib/docker.sock'. Stop docker, remove docker.sock and then start docker and that fixed it. Thanks for your help.